# how to add alert on-click button Submit datatables yajra ? Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have a table data , this table have function delete button . 
this button is successfully delete but i need to add alert on-click confirmation to delete like this :

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?=$row['id']; ?>" 
onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus item ini ?')">[Hapus]</a>
```

but i using datatales serverside i dont know where i put this onclick

its my function delete

```
 public function indexDataTables_pns()
{

    $pns = Data_pns::with('users','master_golongan','master_jabatan')->get();


    return Datatables::of($pns)->addIndexColumn()

    ->addColumn('Nama', function ($pns) {
        return '<a href="/pns/'.$pns->id.'" target="_blank">'.$pns->users->nama.'</a>';   
    })
    ->editColumn('edit', function ($pns) {
        return '<a href="/edit_pns/'.$pns->id.'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
    })
    ->editColumn('hapus', function ($pns) {

        // THIS START HERE FOR DELETE FUNCTION

        $c = csrf_field();
        $m = method_field('DELETE');
    return "<form action='/delete/$pns->id' method='POST'>
            $c
            $m

            <button style='margin-left:10px; width: 30px;' type='submit'

                    class='btn btn-xs btn-danger delete'>
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></i>
            </button>
        </form>";
    })
    ->rawColumns(['Nama' => 'Nama','hapus' => 'hapus','action' => 'action','edit'=>'edit'])
    ->make(true);

}
```

where i can put this onclick and this message ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use it on your delete form's button like

```
<button style='margin-left:10px; width: 30px;' type='submit'
 class='btn btn-xs btn-danger delete' onclick='return confirm("Anda yakin mau 
 menghapus item ini ?")'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></i>
</button>
```

or add a class to your form and use confirmation before submitting the form

```
<form action='/delete/$pns->id' method='POST' class='delete-form'>
```

now add this script in your view file

```
<script>
    $('.delete-form').submit(function(event){
        if(!confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus item ini ?')){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: its all didnt work  sir . this on button submit have a error syntac , i change this ut still didnt work

Comment: check the updated answer. i have edited `" "` position on button.

Comment: can you see this . https://ibb.co/ZhMkJ68 .  , i change this " " . with single ' ' . this is not have error ut still didint work

Comment: it should have worked. can you try the other way i have answered??

Comment: Seems it works for me, by trying the first way, inside the controller.