# why Button onclick didnt work on datatables serverside ? Laravel 6

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have function delete on my table ( using datatables) this delete is work normally but i want to add some pop up alert like "onclick" on my delete , but its didnt work on my button

```
 public function indexDataTables_pns()
{

    $pns = Data_pns::with('users','master_golongan','master_jabatan')->get();


    return Datatables::of($pns)->addIndexColumn()

    ->addColumn('Nama', function ($pns) {
        return '<a href="/pns/'.$pns->id.'" target="_blank">'.$pns->users->nama.'</a>';   
    })
    ->editColumn('edit', function ($pns) {
        return '<a href="/edit_pns/'.$pns->id.'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
    })
    ->editColumn('hapus', function ($pns) {

        $c = csrf_field();
        $m = method_field('DELETE');

    return "<form action='/delete/$pns->id' method='POST')>
            $c
            $m

            <button style='margin-left:10px; width: 30px;' type='submit'
                class='btn btn-xs btn-danger delete' onclick='return 
                confirm('do you want to delete this data ?')'>
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></i>
            </button>
        </form>";
    })
    ->rawColumns(['Nama' => 'Nama','hapus' => 'hapus','action' => 'action','edit'=>'edit'])
    ->make(true);

}
```

its didnt work

i trying adding class

```
<form action='/delete/$pns->id' method='POST' class='delete-form'>
```

and add this script

```
<script>
$('.delete-form').submit(function(event){
    if(!confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus item ini ?')){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but still didnt work . i put this on under my view .

i try to add onsubmit like this

```
<form onsubmit='return confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus item ini ?')'>
```

still didnt work , iam from this thread [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705295/how-to-add-alert-on-click-button-submit-datatables-yajra-laravel/58705524?noredirect=1#comment103706886_58705524) , but i didnt find the answer ..

look this [image](https://ibb.co/ZhMkJ68)

can someone help me ?

---

UPDATE

i tryng add this form class

```
return "<form action='/delete/$pns->id' method='POST' class='delete-form')>
```

this pop up is showing after i click this delete button but this message is null/empty ,

```
 @push('scripts')
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('d_pns') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false,searchable: false},
                { data: 'Nama', name: 'Nama'},
                { data: 'NIP_lama', name: 'NIP_lama'},
                { data: 'NIP_baru', name: 'NIP_baru'},
                { data: 'TMT_CPNS', name: 'TMT_CPNS'},
                { data: 'TMT_PNS', name: 'TMT_PNS'},
                { data: 'TMT_gol_ruang', name: 'TMT_gol_ruang'},
                { data: 'master_golongan.golongan', name: 'master_golongan.golongan'},
                { data: 'master_jabatan.nama_jabatan', name: 'master_jabatan.nama_jabatan'},
                { data: 'edit', name: 'edit', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                { data: 'hapus', name: 'hapus', orderable: false, searchable: false},

            ],
        });
    })
    $('.delete-form').submit(function(event){
      if(!confirm('Anda yakin mau menghapus item ini ?')){
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
</script>

@endpush
```

why this message on confirm is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st attempt issue looks to be escaping the quotes " and '. try putting your message inside double quotes " ". This should resolve your problem

```
<button style='margin-left:10px; width: 30px;' type='submit'
            class='btn btn-xs btn-danger delete' onclick='return 
            confirm("do you want to delete this data ?")'>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></i>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Need to add

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function confirm_delete() {
    return confirm('Apakah anda yakin untuk menghapus data ini ? ');
  }
</script>
```

and add `onclick return confirm_delete()`

Answer (score 0):

I will be dropping this for anyone that need to know how to use onclick from laravel yajra serverside.

```
$datatable = datatables()->collection($data)
     ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '
                    <button type="button" data-security="'.$data->security.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="OrderTicket(\''.$data->security.'\')">Sell
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" data-security="'.$data->security.'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="createRequest(\''.$data->security.'\')">Buy
                    </button>
                ';
    
                return $button;
            })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->make(true);

    return $datatable;
```

All you have to do is to escape the strings `onclick="OrderTicket(\''.$data->security.'\')"`